# Como fazer as perguntas serem aleatórias sem se repetir e rodar um número de questões especifica?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Eu queria fazer com que as questões fossem aleatórias mas que elas não se repetissem rodando as 6 perguntas que compõem cada tema do meu jogo estilo QUIZ, se souberem de um método fácil para meu problema.

Tentei várias pesquisas e não consegui nada talvez porque eu não soube aplicar os conhecimentos mais avançados do pessoal, por favor se puderem explicar detalhadamente eu ficariam muito grato pois sou iniciante.
Desde já agradeço atenção e compreensão. Segue meu script que uso para respostas.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class responder : MonoBehaviour {


private int idTema;
public Text pergunta;
public Text respostaA;
public Text respostaB;
public Text respostaC;
public Text respostaD;
public Text InfoRespostas;
public AudioSource m_Audiosource;   

public string[] perguntas;          //alterei aqui string[] perguntas;  armazena todas as perguntas
public string[] alternativaA;       //armazena todas as alternativas A
public string[] alternativaB;       //armazena todas as alternativas B
public string[] alternativaC;       //armazena todas as alternativas C
public string[] alternativaD;       //armazena todas as alternativas D
public string[] corretas;           //armazena todas as alternativas corretas


private int idPergunta;
private float acertos;
private float questoes;
private float media;
private int notaFinal;

void Start () 
{

    idTema = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("idTema");
    idPergunta = 0;
    questoes = perguntas.Length;

    pergunta.text = perguntas [idPergunta];
    respostaA.text = alternativaA [idPergunta];
    respostaB.text = alternativaB [idPergunta];
    respostaC.text = alternativaC [idPergunta];
    respostaD.text = alternativaD [idPergunta];

    InfoRespostas.text = "Respondendo "+(idPergunta + 1).ToString()+" de "+questoes.ToString()+" perguntas.";
}



public void resposta (string alternativa)
{
    if (alternativa == "A"){
        if (alternativaA [idPergunta] == corretas [idPergunta])
        {
            acertos += 1;
            m_Audiosource.Play ();
        }
        } 

    else if (alternativa == "B") {
        if (alternativaB [idPergunta] == corretas [idPergunta])
        {
            acertos += 1;
            m_Audiosource.Play ();
        }
        }

    else if (alternativa == "C") {
        if (alternativaC [idPergunta] == corretas [idPergunta])
        {
            acertos += 1;
            m_Audiosource.Play ();
        }
        } 

    else if (alternativa == "D") {
        if (alternativaD [idPergunta] == corretas [idPergunta])

        {
            acertos += 1;
            m_Audiosource.Play ();
        }
        }

    proximaPergunta ();
        }


void proximaPergunta()
    {

    idPergunta += 1;  // se fosse 20 questões aqui seria 19
    if(idPergunta <= (questoes-1))
    {
    pergunta.text = perguntas [idPergunta];
    respostaA.text = alternativaA [idPergunta];
    respostaB.text = alternativaB [idPergunta];
    respostaC.text = alternativaC [idPergunta];
    respostaD.text = alternativaD [idPergunta];

    InfoRespostas.text = "Respondendo "+(idPergunta + 1).ToString()+" de "+questoes.ToString()+" perguntas.";

    }

else
        {
        {
            media = 6 * (acertos / questoes);  //calcula a media com base no percentual de acerto
            notaFinal = Mathf.RoundToInt(media); //calcula a nota para o proximo inteiro, segundo a regra da matematica

        if(notaFinal > PlayerPrefs.GetInt("notaFinal"+idTema.ToString()))
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("notaFinal" + idTema.ToString (), notaFinal);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("acertos"+idTema.ToString(), (int) acertos);
        }

            PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("notaFinalTemp" + idTema.ToString (), notaFinal);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("acertosTemp"+idTema.ToString(), (int) acertos);

            SceneManager.LoadScene ("notaFinal");
        }
        }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme fui capaz de entender as suas perguntas são armazenadas em um `array` `public string[] perguntas;` e logo as perguntas são acessadas através de seus índices. Vou lhe ajudar então a criar um algoritmo que gere de forma automática valores inteiros para que você utilize em seu código.

**COMO GERAR NÚMEROS ALEATÓRIOS**

O segredo então é utilizar a `Class Random` para gerar valores aleatórios e através destes valores escolher a pergunta que você deseja.
Para declarar um `Random` faça assim:

```
int valorMin = 0;
int valorMax = 5;
Random random = new Random();
int valorRandomico = random.Next(valorMin, valorMax+1);
```

Dessa forma você terá um valor do tipo *inteiro* atribuído a variável `valorRandomico` entre 0 e 5. É importante observar que estou fazendo uma adição em `valorMax` para quê o valor gerado aleatoriamente fique de fato entre 0 e 5.

**NÚMEROS ALEATÓRIOS QUE NÃO SE REPETEM**

Agora vamos criar um algoritmo que nos retorne valores aleatórios que nunca se repetem. Para fazermos isso utilizaremos uma `List<>` para que sempre que for gerado um novo valor adicionamos a mesma.

Para declarar uma lista faça assim:

```
static List<int> listaPerguntasFeitas = new List<int>();
```

Agora o que precisamos fazer é criar uma função que verifique se um determinado valor já existe cadastrada na lista.

```
static bool ContainsItem(int _numero)
{
    if (listaPerguntasFeitas.Contains(_numero))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Vamos criar também uma função para gerar os valores aleatoriamente, mas esse não verificara ainda se o número gerado por ele já existe. Apenas faz o trabalho bruto.

```
static int RandomNumber(int _min, int _max)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    return random.Next(_min, _max+1);
}
```

Dessa forma temos em mãos o esboço para criarmos o nosso gerador de números não repetidos. O código a seguir finalmente irar gerar as perguntas aleatórias. Criaremos então uma nova função para essa tarefa:

```
static int GerarPergunta(int _quantidaDePerguntasCadastradas)
{
    bool loop = true;
    while (loop)
    {
        int numer = RandomNumber(1, _quantidaDePerguntasCadastradas); // Gera valor aleatório.

        // Se o valor não existe cadastra valor gerado.
        if (ContainsItem(numer) != true)
        {
            listaPerguntasFeitas.Add(numer);
            return numer;
        }

        if (listaPerguntasFeitas.Count >= _quantidaDePerguntasCadastradas)
        {
            loop = false;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Essa função verifica se o valor já foi gerado anteriormente em nossa lista e caso contrario ele cadastra o novo valor gerado e nos retorna através do `return` da função. Podemos notar que a função recebe o parâmetro `_quantidaDePerguntasCadastradas` o propósito disso é para identificarmos se já estouramos o limite de perguntas geradas. Não se preocupe se isso lhe parece muito obscuro e confuso no momento você certamente entendera melhor agora que vamos finalmente utiliza-la.

No método main usaremos finalmente o nosso *Gerador de Perguntas*:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Menu();
    Console.WriteLine("1 Valor gerado: " + GerarPergunta(5));
    Console.WriteLine("2 Valor gerado: " + GerarPergunta(5));
    Console.WriteLine("3 Valor gerado: " + GerarPergunta(5));
    Console.WriteLine("4 Valor gerado: " + GerarPergunta(5));
    Console.WriteLine("5 Valor gerado: " + GerarPergunta(5));

    // Após a função GerarPergunta ser executada 5 vezes o resultado será sempre 0
    Console.WriteLine("\n");
    Console.WriteLine("6 Valor gerado: " + GerarPergunta(5));
    Console.WriteLine("7 Valor gerado: " + GerarPergunta(5));
    Console.WriteLine("8 Valor gerado: " + GerarPergunta(5));

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Vamos compilar o código e vermos o resultado na tela Console:
[image: Print mostrando o resultado da execução]
Como podemos observar após chamarmos o método *GerarPergunta* 5 vezes as próximas vezes ele sempre retornou 0 nos informando que o mesmo já superou a quantidade estipulada.

Poderíamos ainda criar uma função para retornar o tamanho atual da lista:

```
static int TamanhoAtualDaLista()
{
    return listaPerguntasFeitas.Count;
}
```

Dessa forma será possível criar um if antes de tentar gerar qualquer pergunta.
No trecho de código a seguir um loop irar gerar perguntas automaticamente até estourar a quantidade de valores predefinido no método *GerarPergunta();* que neste caso é cinco (5).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int minhaQuantidadeDePerguntas = 5;

    bool loop = true;
    int cont = 1;

    while (loop)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(cont + " Valor gerado: " + GerarPergunta(minhaQuantidadeDePerguntas));
        cont++;
        if (TamanhoAtualDaLista() >= minhaQuantidadeDePerguntas)
        {
            loop = false;
        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Vamos compilar o código novamente para vermos o resultado na tela Console:
[image: Print mostrando o resultado da execução]

O código completo para uso está aqui:

```
static List<int> listaPerguntasFeitas = new List<int>();

static int RandomNumber(int _min, int _max)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    return random.Next(_min, _max+1);
}

static bool ContainsItem(int _numero)
{
    if (listaPerguntasFeitas.Contains(_numero))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

static int TamanhoAtualDaLista()
{
    return listaPerguntasFeitas.Count;
}

static int GerarPergunta(int _quantidaDePerguntasCadastradas)
{
    bool loop = true;
    while (loop)
    {
        int numer = RandomNumber(1, _quantidaDePerguntasCadastradas); // Gera valor aleatório.

        // Se o valor não existe cadastra valor gerado.
        if (ContainsItem(numer) != true)
        {
            listaPerguntasFeitas.Add(numer);
            return numer;
        }

        if (TamanhoAtualDaLista() >= _quantidaDePerguntasCadastradas)
        {
            loop = false;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int minhaQuantidadeDePerguntas = 5;

    bool loop = true;
    int cont = 1;

    while (loop)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(cont + " Valor gerado: " + GerarPergunta(minhaQuantidadeDePerguntas));
        cont++;
        if (TamanhoAtualDaLista() >= minhaQuantidadeDePerguntas)
        {
            loop = false;
        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Agora em seu código no lugar de pergunta.text = perguntas [idPergunta]; você pode usar pergunta.text = perguntas[GerarPergunta(perguntas.Length)];

Comment: perguntas.Length te retorna a quantidade de perguntas que você tem cadastrada ou seja a quantidade de índices. Caso tenha duvidas a respeito do uso do Length acesso link oficial de documentação: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.array.length(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Um grande abraço, qualquer duvida estou a disposição para ajudá-lo.

Comment: aconselho que você faça o [tour] para entender como funciona o site, veja também [Como formatar perguntas e respostas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas)

Comment: Obrigado @Barbetta de fato pude ver que tem tido trabalho editando minhas mensagens. Farei isso em breve. rsrsrs

Comment: Seria interessante mudar o titulo da pergunta para: COMO GERAR VALORES RANDÔMICO QUE NÃO SE REPETEM?

Comment: @GuilhermeLima eu queria agradecer imensamente você atualmente estou viajando quando chegar em casa farei isso, mas pelas explicações que você fez eu com ctz vou conseguir e queria agradecer pela paciência que teve para explicar tão bem os códigos e o funcionamento não encontro muita gente disposto a tirar um pouco do seu tempo para ensinar outras pessoas. Mt obrigado.retornarei a postagem dizendo se deu tudo certo. Mais uma vez obrigado. Abraço e fique com Deus.

Comment: @GuilhermeLima tentei usar o código mas o random.Next não funciona nao sei proque

Comment: @GuilhermeLima e nem o Console.WriteLine  e o Console.ReadKey :(

Comment: A função GerarPergunta possuía um erro! O erro era esse: int numer = RandomNumber(1, 5);

Comment: Para solucionar o erro faça isso: int numer = RandomNumber(1, _quantidaDePerguntasCadastradas); // Gera valor aleatório.

Comment: @GuilhermeLima o random.Next continua sem funcionar e o Write line e o Console.RedKey também. Tem que acessar algum tipo de biblioteca especifica? eu n botei o script no start, tem algum problema?

Comment: @GuilhermeLima as bibliotecas que uso são:
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

Answer (score 1):

Excelente explicação, mas faltou explicar para os mais desatentos que os indices dos arrays começam em 0 e não em 1.
Ou seja, um array com 5 valores o ultimo indice será o numero 4.

```
array(0)="1a pergunta";
array(1)="2a pergunta";
array(2)="3a pergunta";
array(3)="4a pergunta";
array(4)="5a pergunta";
```

E é necessário ter isso em conta no código que gera a lista de perguntas ordenada aleatoriamente.

Comment: Obrigado por esclarecer :)